# d3.js: updating fails to update one element & creates malformed markup

Tags: d3.js

I've got a relatively simple reusable d3.js chart in which I'm trying to finally grasp the Enter-Update-Exit pattern. With some help from SO yesterday, I got it very close to working.

I noticed this morning 2 problems: the Total value is not updating, and it creates malformed markup:

Before update, if I look at the developer tools I see:

```
<g class="total">
    <rect class="total-cluster" x="16" y="61.2" height="121" width="328" rx="4" ry="4"></rect>
    <text class="total-name" x="180" y="155">Total # of Widgets</text>
    <text class="total-value" x="180" y="129">1200</text>
</g>
```

After update:

```
<g class="total">
    <rect class="total-cluster" x="16" y="61.2" height="121" width="328" rx="4" ry="4"></rect>
    <text class="total-name" x="180" y="155">Total # of Widgets</text>
    Total # of Widgets
    </text>
    <text class="total-value" x="180" y="129">1200</text>
    1200
    </text>
</g>
```

I might not notice the malformed markup if it was displaying the correct updated data. But it tells me that updating is happening, but not happening correctly.

**Where is the error in my Total update?**

**Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rolfsf/x2yvwf43/**

My chart script:

```
/**
*  Relative Size Chart for d3.js
*/

function relativeSizeChart() {
var width = 1200,
    margin = 0,
    padding = 16,
    r = d3.scale.linear(),

    onTotalMouseOver = null,
    onTotalClick = null,
    onClusterMouseOver = null,
    onClusterClick = null,

    val = function(d){return d;};
    totalFormat = function(d){return d;};
    clusterFormat = function(d){return d;};
    clusterFormat2 = function(d){return d;};

function chart(selection) {
    selection.each(function(data) {
        //console.log(data);

        var clusterCount = data.Clusters.length,
            totalColWidth = 0.3*width,
            colWidth = (width - totalColWidth)/clusterCount,
            height = colWidth + 2*padding,
            maxRadius = (colWidth - 10)/2;

        var svg = d3.select(this).selectAll("svg")
                    .data([data]);

        var svgEnter = svg
                .enter().append("svg")
                    .attr('class', function(d){
                        if( onTotalMouseOver !== null || onTotalClick !== null ||onClusterMouseOver !== null || onClusterClick !== null){
                            return 'clickable';
                        }else{
                            return 'static';
                        }
                    });

            svgEnter.append('g')
                    .attr('class', 'background');

            svgEnter.append('g')
                    .attr('class', 'headers');

            svgEnter.append('g')
                    .attr('class', 'total');


        var background = svg.selectAll('g.background');

        var headers = svg
                    .selectAll("g.headers")
                    .selectAll("text.header")
                    .data(data.Headers, function(d){return d;});

        var total = svgEnter.selectAll('g.total');

        var cluster = svg.selectAll('g.cluster')
                    .data(data.Clusters,function(d){ return d;});

        var clusterEnter = cluster 
                .enter().append("g")
                    .attr('class', 'cluster')
                    .attr('transform', function (d, i) {
                        return 'translate(' + (totalColWidth + i*colWidth) + ',0)';
                    });

        var clusters = svg.selectAll('g.cluster');


        svg         .attr("width", width)
                    .attr("height", height)
                    .call(responsivefy); 

        r = d3.scale.linear()
                    .domain([0, d3.max(data.Clusters, function(d){return d[1];})])
                    .range([40, maxRadius]);           

        svgEnter    .selectAll("g.background").append("rect")
                    .attr("class", "chart-bg")
                    .attr('x', 0)
                    .attr('y', padding)
                    .attr('height', (height-padding))
                    .attr('width', width)
                    .attr('class', 'chart-bg');

        svgEnter    .selectAll("g.background").append("g")
                    .attr('class', 'cluster-lines');

        svgEnter    .selectAll("g.background").append("line")
                    .attr("class", "centerline")
                    .attr('x1', (totalColWidth - padding))
                    .attr('x2', width - (colWidth/2))
                    .attr('y1', (height+padding)/2)
                    .attr('y2', (height+padding)/2);

        var clusterLines = svg.select('g.cluster-lines')
                    .selectAll("line")
                    .data(data.Clusters,function(d){ return d;})
                    .enter().append('line')
                    .attr('class', 'cluster-line');

        headers     .enter().append('text')
                    .attr('class', 'header');

        total       .append("rect")
                    .attr("class", "total-cluster")
                    .attr('x', padding)
                    .attr('y', 0.2*(height+(4*padding)))
                    .attr('height', 0.5*(height))
                    .attr('width', totalColWidth-(2*padding))
                    .attr('rx', 4)
                    .attr('ry', 4)
                    .on('mouseover', onTotalMouseOver)
                    .on('click', onTotalClick);

        total       .append("text")
                    .attr("class", "total-name")
                    .attr('x', totalColWidth/2 )
                    .attr('y', function(d, i) { return ((height+padding)/2) + (padding + 10); });

        total       .append("text")
                    .attr("class", "total-value")
                    .attr('x', totalColWidth/2 )
                    .attr('y', function(d, i) { return ((height+padding)/2); })
                    .text(totalFormat(0));

        clusterEnter.append('circle')
                    .attr('class', 'bubble')
                    .attr('cx', function(d, i) { return colWidth/2; })
                    .attr('cy', function(d, i) { return (height+padding)/2;})
                    .attr("r", "50")
                    .on('mouseover', function(d, i, j) {
                        if (onClusterMouseOver != null) onClusterMouseOver(d, i, j);
                    })
                    .on('mouseout', function() { /*do something*/ })
                    .on('click', function(d, i){ 
                        onClusterClick(this, d, i); 
                    });  


        clusterEnter.append('text')
                    .attr('class', 'cluster-value')
                    .attr('x', function(d, i) { return colWidth/2; })
                    .attr('y', function(d, i) { return ((height+padding)/2); })
                    .text(clusterFormat(0)); 


        clusterEnter.append('text')
                    .attr('class', 'cluster-value-2')
                    .attr('x', function(d, i) { return colWidth/2; })
                    .attr('y', function(d, i) { return ((height+padding)/2) + (padding + 10); })
                    .text(clusterFormat2(0));

        //update attributes
        clusterLines.attr('x1', function(d, i) { return totalColWidth + i*colWidth })
                    .attr('x2', function(d, i) { return totalColWidth + i*colWidth })
                    .attr('y1', function(d, i) { return padding })
                    .attr('y2', function(d, i) { return (height); });

        headers     .attr('x', function(d, i) { 
                        if(i === 0){
                            return (totalColWidth/2);
                        }else{
                            return (totalColWidth + (i*colWidth) - (colWidth/2))
                        }
                    })
                    .attr('y', 12);

       //clean up old 
        svg          .exit().remove();

        cluster      .exit().selectAll('circle.bubble')
                     .style("opacity", 1)
                     .style("fill", "#DDD")
                     .style("stroke", "#DDD")
                     .transition()
                     .duration(500)
                     .style("opacity", 0);

        cluster      .exit().remove();
        headers      .exit().remove();

        //update with data            
        function update(data) {

            svg         .selectAll('text.total-value')
                        .transition()
                        .delay(100)
                        .duration(1000)
                        .tween( 'text', function(d) {
                            var currentValue = +this.textContent.replace(/\D/g,''); 
                            var interpolator = d3.interpolateRound( currentValue, d.Total[1] );
                            return function( t ) {
                                this.textContent = totalFormat(interpolator(t));
                            };
                        });  

            svg         .selectAll('text.total-name')
                        .text(val(data.Total[0]));

            svg         .selectAll('circle')
                        .attr('class', function(d, i) { 
                            if(d[1] === 0){ return 'bubble empty';}
                            else {return 'bubble';}
                        })
                        .transition()
                        .duration(1000)
                        .delay(function(d, i) { return 100 + (i * 100); })
                        .ease('elastic')   
                        .attr("r", function (d, i) { return r(d[1]); });

            svg         .selectAll('text.cluster-value')
                        .transition()
                        .delay(function(d, i) { return 100 + (i * 100); })
                        .duration(1000)
                        .tween( 'text', function(d, i) {
                            var currentValue = +this.textContent.replace(/\D/g,'');
                            var interpolator = d3.interpolateRound( currentValue, d[1] );
                            return function( t ) {
                                this.textContent = clusterFormat(interpolator(t));
                            };
                        });  


            svg         .selectAll('text.cluster-value-2')
                        .transition()
                        .delay(function(d, i) { return 100 + (i * 100); })
                        .duration(1000)
                        .tween( 'text', function(d, i) {
                            var currentValue = +this.textContent.replace(/\D/g,'');
                            var interpolator = d3.interpolateRound( currentValue, d[0] );
                            return function( t ) {
                                this.textContent = clusterFormat2(interpolator(t));
                            };
                        });  

            headers     .text(function(d, i){return d});
        }


        //http://www.brendansudol.com/posts/responsive-d3/
        function responsivefy(svg) {
            // get container + svg aspect ratio
            //var SVG = d3.select(selection).selectAll('svg');
            var container = d3.select(svg.node().parentNode),
                width = parseInt(svg.style("width")),
                height = parseInt(svg.style("height")),
                aspect = width / height;

            // add viewBox and preserveAspectRatio properties,
            // and call resize so that svg resizes on inital page load
            svg .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + width + " " + height)
                .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMin meet")
                .call(resize);

            // to register multiple listeners for same event type, 
            // you need to add namespace, i.e., 'click.foo'
            // necessary if you call invoke this function for multiple svgs
            // api docs: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#on
            d3.select(window).on("resize." + container.attr("id"), resize);

            // get width of container and resize svg to fit it
            function resize() {
                var targetWidth = parseInt(container.style("width"));
                svg.attr("width", targetWidth);
                svg.attr("height", Math.round(targetWidth / aspect));
            }
        }

        update(data);

    });


}

chart.totalFormat = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return totalFormat;
    totalFormat = _;
    return chart;
};
chart.clusterFormat = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return clusterFormat;
    clusterFormat = _;
    return chart;
};
chart.clusterFormat2 = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return clusterFormat2;
    clusterFormat2 = _;
    return chart;
};



chart.width = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return width;
    width = _;
    return chart;
};
chart.onTotalClick = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return onTotalClick;
    onTotalClick = _;
    return chart;
};

chart.onTotalMouseOver = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return onTotalMouseOver;
    onTotalMouseOver = _;
    return chart;
};

chart.onClusterClick = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return onClusterClick;
    onClusterClick = _;
    return chart;
};

chart.onClusterMouseOver = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return onClusterMouseOver;
    onClusterMouseOver = _;
    return chart;
};


return chart;
}
```

and here's my data:

```
var data = {
"data1": {
    Headers: ["Total", "Col 1A", "Col 2A", "Col 3A", "Col 4A"],
    Total: ["Total # of Widgets", 1200],
    Clusters: [
        [100, 1200],
        [67, 800],
        [42, 500],
        [17, 198]
    ]
},
"data2": {
    Headers: ["Total", "Col 1B", "Col 2B", "Col 3B", "Col 4B"],
    Total: ["Total # of Widgets", 1201],
    Clusters: [
        [20, 245],
        [31, 371],
        [32, 386],
        [12, 146]
    ]
}
}
```

and I call it like so:

```
        d3  .select('#overview-graph')
        .datum(data[term])
        .call(relativeSizeChart()
            .totalFormat(function(d) { return d })
            .clusterFormat(function(d) { return d })
            .clusterFormat2(function(d) { return d + '%'})
        );
```

Comment: I think the problem is that you're setting `this.textContent` in your text tweens -- you're not supposed to set anything in the tween functions, just return the current value. Does [this](http://jsfiddle.net/x2yvwf43/1/) fix it? Sorry, the whole thing is quite complex so I'm not 100% sure if this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks Lars. Your fiddle doesn't update any of the text values, so I can't fully judge it. But your comment makes me realize I should probably start by stripping out all the transitions and get it working that way first. Then bring in transitions.   As for this.textContent in some uses, my # values might actually be a currency abbreviation like $25M, so I'm stripping the non-numeric characters before doing the tween.

Comment: Ok, as I've said, I'm not entirely sure what exactly you're expecting.

Comment: very simply, I expect the text elements to update with the new data. All of them update except for the Total.

Comment: Ok, so the DOM structure is ok for me (Chrome) with your original example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DOM structure looks OK for me in Firefox.

In your `update` function you're doing this:

```
    function update(data) {

        svg         .selectAll('text.total-value')
                    .transition()
                    .delay(100)
                    .duration(1000)
                    .tween( 'text', function(d) {
                        var currentValue = +this.textContent.replace(/\D/g,''); 
                        var interpolator = d3.interpolateRound( currentValue, d.Total[1] );
                        return function( t ) {
                            this.textContent = totalFormat(interpolator(t));
                        };
                    });
```

If you look in your `tween` function, you are interpolating to the value `d.Total[1]`.  `d` is not set to your data in this case.  That pattern is typically what you'd use if you had data bound to the element.  I think instead you want:

```
            svg         .selectAll('text.total-value')
                        .transition()
                        .delay(100)
                        .duration(1000)
                        .tween( 'text', function(d) {
                            var currentValue = +this.textContent.replace(/\D/g,'');
                            debugger;
                            var interpolator = d3.interpolateRound( currentValue, data.Total[1] );
                            return function( t ) {
                                this.textContent = totalFormat(interpolator(t));
                            };
                        });
```

The only difference is on this line:

```
var interpolator = d3.interpolateRound( currentValue, data.Total[1] );
```

where I'm using `data` instead of `d`

An updated fiddle is at: http://jsfiddle.net/x2yvwf43/4/

Comment: So is `d` the old data, and `data` is the new? And why does it work for the cluster-values, but not the total-value? I suppose I've done something differently with the two groups earlier in the script that I need to clear up.
2nd time this week, Ben! Thanks so much!

Comment: cool - playing with that bit of info, I now have it behaving more as I had intended: http://jsfiddle.net/rolfsf/a62g1owf/  Seems like I'm binding data in more places than I need to, so maybe I can simplify.

Comment: I didn't actually look to hard to determine what your `d` variable contains.  I expect it's old data, as the `text` element doesn't have any data bound to it if I remember correctly without actually checking.  In which case, it worked for the `cluster-values` because these do have bound data, so `d` will be set in your function to update the information.